# numpy Boolean array representation of an integer

Tags: python, numpy

What's the easiest way to produce a numpy Boolean array representation of an integer?  For example, map `6` to `np.array([False, True, True], dtype=np.bool)`.

Comment: This question has unfortunately no useful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773443/built-in-function-in-numpy-to-interpret-an-integer-to-an-array-of-boolean-values

Comment: What's wrong with the accepted answer to the question that you linked? I apologize if I'm not reading something correctly, but the accepted answer to that question seems to outline pretty neatly how to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @VladislavMartin I have to convert my integer to an array of `np.int8`, which is ugly, and the output puts most significant bits first, and groups the bits into groups of 8 — neither are things I want.

Comment: In your one example, the order of the bits is ambiguous.  Please add the comment about the order of the bits to the question.  Perhaps include the expected output for the integer 8.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `n` is the integer, the expression `(n & (1 << np.arange(int(floor(log(n, 2) + 1))))) > 0` will create a boolean array representing the bits, with the least significant bit in the first position.

For example,

```
In [224]: n = 5

In [225]: from math import floor, log

In [226]: n = 5

In [227]: (n & (1 << np.arange(int(floor(log(n, 2) + 1))))) > 0
Out[227]: array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [228]: n = 8

In [229]: (n & (1 << np.arange(int(floor(log(n, 2) + 1))))) > 0
Out[229]: array([False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [230]: n = 514

In [231]: (n & (1 << np.arange(int(floor(log(n, 2) + 1))))) > 0
Out[231]: array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Clever!  I'm actually specifying the `m = int(floor(log(n, 2) + 1))`, so this solution is the shortest for me.

Answer (score 2):

First, use [`np.binary_repr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.binary_repr.html) to get the binary representation of the integer value. Remember to specify the bit-width you desire for your bit array here. I have included a way to programmatically determine the number of bits required to represent the given integer:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> bin_n = bin(n)
'0b101'
>>> smallest_length = n.bit_length()
3
>>> bin_array = np.binary_repr(5, width=smallest_length)
bin_array = '101'
```

Then, reverse the order of the bits in the output binary string:

```
>> reversed_bin_array[::-1]
reversed_bin_array = '101'
```

Then, finally to get an array of bits with the earlier-specified bit-width, use [`bitarray`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/). I have found that the `bitarray` object is a very useful means to conveniently store and operate on bit arrays:

```
>>> bitarray('11110010') # from a string
```

I hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: `np.invert` does not reverse the order of the bits.

Comment: Wow... what was I thinking? Well, fixed it. Does that look better @user2357112

Comment: Sort of, but you have a lingering reference to the order of the bits being "already reversed by the previous step". Also, it looks like the questioner wants to autocompute the smallest required width instead of specifying a width manually, and for completeness, you should probably show how to get the NumPy array the questioner asked for out of this.

Comment: @user2357112 I see. All of those are good points, I've made changes to my answer to address each of them - please let me know if I've yet to present my answer is a satisfactory manner. It's important that anyone who sees this would get some use out of it (especially the OP!) :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using [`np.binary_repr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.binary_repr.html) and [`np.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) -

```
np.fromstring(np.binary_repr(num), dtype=np.uint8)==49
```

Sample run -

```
In [39]: num
Out[39]: 17

In [40]: np.fromstring(np.binary_repr(num), dtype=np.uint8)==49
Out[40]: array([ True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not the easiest, but a compact way is

`from numpy import array
array([i for i in bin(5)[2:]]) == '1'`